# In order to access data elsewhere in java, where should I place it?

Tags: java

I want to put data which is from a file to a variable, then I can access it elsewhere(in other classes) conveniently. I know the `file path` and read it to a variable. Then I place it in a Class. The data **won't be changed** and have **only one** copy.

```
// store data in a static field
public class MyContainer {
  private static Map<String, MyClass> data;
  public static void setData(Map<String, MyClass> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
  public static Map<String, MyClass> getData(){
    return data;
  }
}

// set data at one place
Map<String, MyClass> data = new HashMap<>();
MyContainer.setData(data);

// access data at other places
MyContainer.getData(data);
```

Though the code above can achieve this, I think **it's bad** because I could access it before assigning data to it.
How to implement this correctly?

Comment: A lazy initialized [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) would be one possibility. Make sure you design the object immutable though.

Answer (score 0):

If the data never changes, set it in the constructor and remove the setter. Also get rid of the `static` keywords.

```
public class MyContainer {
    private final Map<String, MyClass> data = new HashMap<>();
    public MyContainer(@Nonnull Map<String, MyClass> data) {
        this.data.putAll(data);
    }
    public Map<String, MyClass> getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

And you might want to return `Collections.unmodifiableMap(data);`, so `data` cannot be modified from outside.

Comment: You should also suggest the OP to have a provider giving them the corresponding instance that they can use throughout the code. Or suggest to pass the created instance to all the classes and methods that need it. Otherwise their question is not fully answered

Answer (score -1):

Use getter methods. If you're worried about a class attempting to access it before it's ready, handle this in the getter.

```
private boolean allowAccess; // set this to true once you're happy that the data is ready to read
public Map<String, MyClass> getData() {
  if (!allowAccess) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }
  return data;
}
```